# Replace spaces with %20, but doesn't print last word

Tags: c

I'm currently doing the exercises from "Cracking the coding interview". And even though the answer to this problem seems to be in many versions out there. I'm not able to work mine properly.
I've checked the other versions in stackoverflow but I'm not able to find the difference or what's causing me this problem.

THE PROBLEM: it does change spaces for '%20' but it does not print the last word.

EXAMPLE:

> Input: "Mr John Smith
>
> Output: "Mr%20John%20"

I leave you here my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 /* Maximum sentence size + 1. */
 #define MAX_SENTENCE_SZ 256

 int amountOfSpaces(char* str){
   int cnt=0;

   while(*str!='\0'){
     if(*str == ' '){
       cnt++;
     }
     str++;
   }
   return cnt;
}

int main(){

  char sentence[100]={'\0'};

   /* Get the sentence, with size limit. */
   fgets (sentence, MAX_SENTENCE_SZ, stdin);

   /* Remove trailing newline, if there. */
   if ((strlen(sentence)>0) && (sentence[strlen (sentence) - 1] == '\n'))
    sentence[strlen (sentence) - 1] = '\0';

   int cant = amountOfSpaces(sentence);
   int newleng = sizeof(sentence) + cant*2;

   char *ans = (char *)malloc(newleng+sizeof(char));
   int pos=0;
   for(int i=0; i<= sizeof(sentence)-1; i++,pos++){
      if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
        ans[pos] = '%';
        ans[pos + 1] = '2';
        ans[pos + 2] = '0';
        pos += 3;
      } else {
        ans[pos] = sentence[i];
      }
    }
    ans[pos+1]='\0';
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(sentence));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(ans));
    printf("%s",ans);
      /* Free memory and exit. */
      free (ans);
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: don't do `sizeof(ans)`

Comment: Your code runs off the end of the input string (you should stop at the end of the string, not the end of the entire buffer)

Comment: I've just realized, I'll change it in when I get home.

Comment: besides the fact that you should put the `\0` at `newleng` you could use a single `sprintf` instead of 3 `ans[pos] =` statements

Comment: What Paulo said: 'Start using a debugger, get familiar with it.'  If you cannot debug, you should not be writing code.

Comment: I added a detailed answer of every problem I found in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code

1. don't call `strlen` every time you need the length, it computes the length, so it's expensive

   ```
   sentenceLength = strlen(sentence);
   /* Remove trailing newline, if there. */
   if ((sentenceLength > 0) && (sentence[sentenceLength - 1] == '\0'))
       sentence[--sentenceLength] = '\0';

   int cant = amountOfSpaces(sentence);
   ```
2. You already have the length of the string, and `sizeof sentence` is `100`, that is not the length of the string

   ```
   int newleng = sentenceLength + 2 * cant;
   ```
3. You don't need to cast `malloc`, and you need one extra character for the terminating '\0'

   ```
   char *ans = malloc(1 + newleng);
   size_t pos = 0;
   ```
4. Since you already have the length, use it also the same `sizeof` error

   ```
   for(size_t i=0 ; i < sentenceLength ; i++, pos++){
       if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
           ans[pos] = '%';
           ans[pos + 1] = '2';
           ans[pos + 2] = '0';
   ```
5. You are incrementing `pos` at every iteration so here you increment it by 2

   ```
           pos += 2;
       } else {
           ans[pos] = sentence[i];
       }
   }
   ```
6. `pos + 1` is wrong, you already increment it in the loop.

   ```
   ans[pos] = '\0';

   printf("%lu\n", sentenceLength);
   printf("%lu\n", pos);
   printf("%s",ans);
   /* Free memory and exit. */
   free (ans);
   return 0;
   ```

The complete fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Maximum sentence size + 1. */
#define MAX_SENTENCE_SZ 256

int amountOfSpaces(char* str) {
    int cnt=0;
    while(*str!='\0') {
        if(*str == ' ') {
            cnt++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main(){
    char sentence[100];
    size_t sentenceLength;

    /* Get the sentence, with size limit. */
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);

    sentenceLength = strlen(sentence);
    /* Remove trailing newline, if there. */
    if ((sentenceLength > 0) && (sentence[sentenceLength - 1] == '\0'))
        sentence[--sentenceLength] = '\0';

    int cant = amountOfSpaces(sentence);

    int newleng = sentenceLength + 2 * cant;

    char *ans = malloc(1 + newleng);
    size_t pos = 0;

    for(size_t i=0 ; i < sentenceLength ; i++, pos++) {
        if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
            ans[pos] = '%';
            ans[pos + 1] = '2';
            ans[pos + 2] = '0';

            pos += 2;
        } else {
            ans[pos] = sentence[i];
        }
    }

    ans[pos] = '\0';

    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sentenceLength);
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)pos);
    printf("%s",ans);
    /* Free memory and exit. */
    free (ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Complete and nearly flawless +1.  Minor nits: 1) Use `printf("%zu\n", sentenceLength);` or `printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long) sentenceLength);`  2) Better to use `size_t pos,i`  3) Use `sentence[--sentenceLength] = '\0';` else length is too long.

Answer (score 0):

> ...I'm not able to find [...] what's causing me this problem.

Start using a debugger, get familiar with it.

Anyway:

```
  if (sentence[i] == ' ') {
    ans[pos] = '%';
    ans[pos + 1] = '2';
    ans[pos + 2] = '0';
    pos += 2;  // <<<<< BUG HERE -- increment by 2 not 3
  } else {
```

Because `pos` is already incremented by 1 at each `for` iteration.

Btw: instead of using `sizeof(sentence)` store the actual length of the string in a variable and use that:

```
int l = strlen(sentence);
```

Remember `l` won't include the trailing null character.